# going down theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, ac.commutative-algebra

Typical maps that satisfy "going down theorem" are flat morphisms and integral extensions of normal rings that are integral.

Let $Spec(B)\rightarrow Spec(A)$ be a finite type morphism of k-noetherian algebras (k be a field) that satisfy going down theorem, is there any " factorisation result" for such morphims?

Comment: What sort of factorization do you want?

Comment: for example faithfully flat followed by integral.

Comment: Then no.  Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain with non-torsion class group.  Let $P$ be a prime of infinite order in said group.  Let $B = \bigcap_{Q \in \text{Max} A, Q \neq P} A_Q$.  Then I *think* $B$ is of finite type over $A$ (or anyway, I know some examples where it is), but it isn't faithfully flat (since $PB=B$), nor integral (since $A$ is integrally closed and has the same fraction field as $B$).  And there's essentially nothing between $A$ and $B$ to make a factorization out of.  But $B$ is going down over $A$.